# No se como hacer el llamado correcto de vectores en parámetros por referencia

Tags: c++, parametros, vectores, fórmulas-de-matriz

Hola estoy haciendo la corrección de un examen en lenguaje de c++, el main va llenar la matriz(20 espacios) "matrizvalores" con los numeros fibonacci y estos seran enviados a la funcionfibonacci la cual determinara cual de esos números son primos o no. Los numeros no primos se guardan en el vector "no primos", los cuales se envian a  la función Imprimirnoprimos que como su nombre indica va imprimirlos. Pero el programa no funciona por la llamada de parámetros por referencia y no se como arreglarlo, es decir no logro enviar la matriz a las funciones.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
void funcionfibonacci(int matrizvalores [5][4]);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int noprimos[20]);
int main(){
    int matrizvalores [5][4],c,b,a;
    c = 0;
    b = 1;
    a = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
        for( int j = 0; j < 4; j++){
            c = a+b;
            matrizvalores[i][j] = c;
            a = b;
        }
    }
    funcionfibonacci(&matrizvalores);
    return 0;
}

    
    
    void funcionfibonacci(  int *matrizvalores [5][4]){
        int a, noprimos[20];
        int e = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i <5; i++){
            for (int j = 0 ; j < 4; j++){
                for ( int d = 1; d < matrizvalores[i][j]; d++){
                    if(matrizvalores[i][j]% d == 0){
                        a++;
                    }
                }
                if(a == 2){
                    printf("El numero es primo %d.\n", matrizvalores[i][j]);
                    
                }
                else{
                    
                    noprimos[e]= matrizvalores[i][j];
                    e++;
                }
            }
            
            imprimirNoPrimos(&noprimos);
            
            
            
        }
    }
        
        void imprimirNoPrimos( int *noprimos[20])
        {
            for(int i = 0; i <20; i++)
            {
                printf("Los numeros no primos son %d.\n", noprimos[i]);
            }
            
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

En primer lugar, no pareces tener claro lo que es una referencia. Declaras tus funciones para recibir formaciones<sup>1</sup> de enteros:

```
void funcionfibonacci(int matrizvalores [5][4]);
//                    ^^^ <--- Entero (int)
void imprimirNoPrimos(int noprimos[20]);
//                    ^^^ <--- Entero (int)
```

Pero las defines para recibir formaciones de punteros a enteros:

```
void funcionfibonacci(  int *matrizvalores [5][4]){
//                      ^^^^^ <--- Puntero a entero (int *)
   ...
}

void imprimirNoPrimos( int *noprimos[20])
//                     ^^^^^ <--- Puntero a entero (int *)
{
   ...
}
```

Esto me lleva a pensar que no tienes claros importantes conceptos básicos de C++:

- Declaración y definición.
- Parámetros por copia y referencia.
- Decaída a puntero.

---

###### Declaración y definición

(Casi) cualquier símbolo en C++ puede ser declarado y definido por separado. Declarar `X` le dice al compilador "*El símbolo `X` existe, pero no te voy a dar detalles del mismo*", definir `X` le dice al compilador "*El síbmolo `X` existe, y es exáctamente de esta manera*", si defines un símbolo sin previamente declararlo la definición cuenta como declaración. Por lo tanto estás declarando dos funciones `funcionfibonacci` y `imprimirNoPrimos`:

```
void funcionfibonacci(int matrizvalores [5][4]);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int noprimos[20]);
```

Pero las dejas sin definir, y estás declarando-y-definiendo otras dos funciones:

```
void funcionfibonacci(int *matrizvalores [5][4]);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int *noprimos[20]);
```

###### Parámetros por copia y referencia

Una función puede recibir parámetros por copia o por referencia, un parámetro por copia tiene el nombre de su tipo y el nombre del parámetro:

```
void funcion(tipo p);
//                ^ <--- 'p' es un argumento de tipo 'tipo', 'p' es una instancia de 'tipo'
//                        cuando se llame a 'funcion', se copiará en 'p' los datos del objeto
//                        con el que se llame a la función.
```

Un parámetro por referencia tiene el nombre de su tipo, seguido de un [et](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/%26) y el nombre del parámetro:

```
void funcion(tipo &p);
//                 ^ <--- 'p' es un argumento de tipo 'tipo &', 'p' es una referencia a 'tipo'
//                         cuando se llame a 'funcion', 'p' referenciará los datos del objeto
//                         con el que se llame a la función.
```

En tu caso no has usado el et en ninguna declaración o en ninguna definición, así que no estás usando referencias.

###### Decaída a puntero

En C++ no se pueden pasar formaciones por copia (tampoco en C) así que las funciones que reciben una formación como parámetro transforman dicha formación a puntero:

| El parámetro ... | ... se interpreta como... | ... que es |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `int matrizvalores[5][4]` | `int (*matrizvalores)[4])` | Puntero a una formación de cuatro enteros |
| `int noprimos[20]` | `int *noprimos` | Puntero a entero |
| `int *matrizvalores [5][4]` | `int (*matrizvalores)[5][4]` | Puntero a una formación de enteros de cinco filas y cuatro columnas |
| `int *noprimos[20]` | `int (*noprimos)[20]` | Puntero a una formación de veinte enteros |

Una vez aclarado lo anterior, veamos cómo puedes pasar formaciones por referencia.

---

Una referencia a formación se declara así:

```
tipo (&nombre)[tamaño]
```

Por lo tanto, tus funciones `funcionfibonacci` y `noprimos` deberían ser declaradas (y definidas) así:

```
void funcionfibonacci(int (&matrizvalores)[5][4]);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int (&noprimos)[20]);
```

Si esta notación te parece muy confusa, puedes usar un alias de tipo:

```
using int_5x4 = int[5][4];
using int_20 = int[20];

void funcionfibonacci(int_5x4 &matrizvalores);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int_20 &noprimos);
```

Teniendo en cuenta eso y programando como en C++ contemporáneo, tu código podría parecerse a:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

using int_5x4 = int[5][4];
using int_20 = int[20];

void funcionfibonacci(int_5x4 &matrizvalores);
void imprimirNoPrimos(int_20 &noprimos);

int main()
{
    int_5x4 matrizvalores;
    int c = 0, b = 0, a = 0;

    for (auto &fila : matrizvalores) {
        for (auto &valor : fila) {
            valor = (c = a + b);
            a = b;
        }
    }

    funcionfibonacci(matrizvalores);

    return 0;
}

void funcionfibonacci(int_5x4 &matrizvalores) {
    int_20 noprimos;
    int a;
    int e = 0;

    for (const auto &fila : matrizvalores) {
        for (const auto &valor : fila) {
            for (int d = 1; d < valor; ++d) {
                a += ((valor % d) == 0);
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                cout << "El numero " << valor << " es primo %d.\n";
            }
            else {
                noprimos[e] = valor;
                e++;
            }
        }

        imprimirNoPrimos(noprimos);
    }
}

void imprimirNoPrimos(int_20 &noprimos)
{
    for (const auto &valor : noprimos)
    {
        cout << "Los numeros no primos son " << valor << ".\n";
    }
}
```

---

###### <sup>1</sup>También conocida como *arreglo* o en inglés *array*.